# Every time I parent my eyes to a bone, the eye goes below the model

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, rigging, armature

I'm trying to *Parent* my eye to my model's armature, but for some reason, every time I do the eye goes way below my model in the process.

I should also point out a few things:

1. My eyes are separate objects so that I can rig them later with the same armature.
2. I also can't seem to weight paint my object to the bone because overtime I rotate the object it doesn't seem to rotate to the head. (I know this because I tried placing the eyes back in the sockets of my model and rotated the bone to see how that could turn out).

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The thing selected on the bottom is the eye and the other one has not been parented to the bone yet...

Comment: I should also point out a few things:                                                                   1. My eyes are separate objects so that I can rig them later with the same armature.                                                                                                         2. I also can't seem to weight paint my object to the bone because overtime I rotate the object it doesn't seem to rotate to the head. (I know this because I tried placing the eyes back in the sockets of my model and rotated the bone to see how that could turn out.)

Comment: Can you upload a .blend file?

Comment: It happens when either your armature is not at rest pose, or, more possibly, your eye balls have other parenting value prior to being parented to the armature. So either make sure your armature is at rest pose or, select your eye ball, press alt + p, and select "clear parent and apply visual transformation", and then parent it to the bone again.